# Shell in .Net displaying file not found

Tags: vb.net

Folks,

I was using
 Shell("LPR -P " & IP & " -S " & IP & "c:\label.txt", AppWinStyle.Hide) 
in my code earlier in my code to send print to printer. suddenlt it stopped working. i started getting file not found error. then i chanegd my code to below, but still no show. now i an getting the following error

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was caught
>   ErrorCode=-2147467259   Message=The system cannot find the file
>   specified   NativeErrorCode=2   Source=System   StackTrace:        at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo)        at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()        at
>   xxxxxx.LPRProcess(String pstrFilePath, String pstrQueue, String
>   pstrPrinter) in I:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\xxxxxx\ScanInSn.vb:line
>   201   InnerException:

New code

```
 Private Function LPRProcess(ByVal pstrFilePath As String, ByVal pstrQueue As String, ByVal pstrPrinter As String) 
    Dim prcLprInfo As New ProcessStartInfo 
    prcLprInfo.FileName = "Lpr" 
    prcLprInfo.CreateNoWindow = True 
    prcLprInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden 
    prcLprInfo.UseShellExecute = False 
    prcLprInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True 
    prcLprInfo.Arguments = "-S " & pstrPrinter & " -P " & pstrQueue & " """ & pstrFilePath & """" 
    Dim prcLpr As New Process 
    Dim strOutput As String 
    Try 
        'Stage = "Run Process.Start( )" 
        prcLpr.StartInfo = prcLprInfo 
        prcLpr.Start() 
        strOutput = prcLpr.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() 
        'Stage = "Process started, wait for it to exit" 
        If Not prcLpr.HasExited Then prcLpr.WaitForExit() 
    Catch ex As Exception 
        Throw New Exception("Error running LPR process: " & ex.Message) 
    Finally 
        prcLpr.Close() 
        prcLpr.Dispose() 
    End Try 
    If strOutput.Length > 0 Then 
        Throw New Exception("LPR ERROR: " & strOutput) 
    End If 
End Function
```

Any ideas? (using .net 4.0)

Comment: Why is your question tagged with C#? What does this programming language has to do with the code that you have shown in your question? Also please read some formatting tips to improve readability of your code: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Currently your code snippet is a completely unreadable random bit of characters repulsing anyone willing to help you.

Comment: Can you fully qualify the Lpr executable? Like "C:\MyApp\Lpr.exe"?

Comment: If you try that command from the commandline it works?

Comment: yes, works from my command prompt. using Shell("LPR -P " & IP & " -S " & IP & "c:\label.txt", But for some reason i am getting file not found error what i try to run it from my code.

Comment: i copied lpr.exe from system32 to c:\windows\syswow64 and now i am not getting file not found error. but still not printing?

Comment: after copying the lpr.exe into my 64 bit folder everything worked fine. but when i created a setup and trying to install and run the application its not printing. any ideas???

Comment: Folks, I fugured in my development evniornment i found a way round by copying lpr.exe into syswow64 bit folder. But the installation computer is running on 32 bit os and its dosent seems to response on it. i think my VS2010 need to be configured or my setup project needs to be configure properly. i tried everything settings to change the project and setup project to 32 bit but still no show. any ideas??

Comment: looks like permissions issue on the folder where the label.txtx is kept

Comment: still not working any ideas any one?

Comment: resolved the issue by changing Visual Studio > project > properties > Compile > Target CUP. Settings to AnyCPU. It was set to 64 bit. Thank you Tom and Steve for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue by changing settings in Visual Studio Project Prpperties.

Visual Studio > project > properties > Compile > Target CUP.

Changes the Settings to "AnyCPU".

It was set to 64 bit.

Thank you Tom and Steve for your help..